# Plot variable sums on y axis of a histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

I have data (from DNA sequencing) like this:

```
read.lengths = c(100, 100, 200, 250, 300, 400, 400, 500, 500)
```

Each length is just a number of DNA bases in a read. It's simple to plot a histogram of read lengths vs. counts, given any number of bins.

```
ggplot(data.frame(read.lengths)) + geom_histogram(aes(x = read.lengths))
```

But what I'd like to do is put the total number of bases on the y axis, not the count of the reads. I.e. for each bin in the histogram, I want the sum of all the read lengths in that bin on the Y axis.

Comment: Not very clear, are you trying to have yaxis max as 500 (because you have longest read as 500) ? Can you show example plot, hand drawn, or a weblink?

Comment: Draw what you want. With paint or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462865/plot-variable-sums-on-y-axis-of-a-histogram/46464031#46464031) which made me see it in the right way, I tried out some ggplot magic, and it seems to work perfectly.

```
ggplot(data.frame(read.lengths)) + geom_histogram(aes(x = read.lengths, y = (..count..*x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
read.lengths <- c(100, 100, 200, 250, 300, 400, 400, 500, 500)
read.lengths.cat <- as.factor(read.lengths)

read.lengths.data <- data.frame(read.lengths.cat, read.lengths)

read.lengths.data <- aggregate(read.lengths ~ read.lengths.cat, 
            data = read.lengths.data, sum)

ggplot(aes(x = read.lengths.cat, y = read.lengths), 
       data = read.lengths.data) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```